# kubernetes make error:touch: _output/bin/prerelease-lifecycle-gen: No such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes

```
➜  kubernetes git:(master) make generated_files
+++ [0121 20:12:36] Building go targets for darwin/amd64:
    ./vendor/k8s.io/code-generator/cmd/prerelease-lifecycle-gen
touch: _output/bin/prerelease-lifecycle-gen: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [_output/bin/prerelease-lifecycle-gen] Error 1
make: *** [generated_files] Error 2

➜  kubernetes git:(master) pwd
$GOPATH/src/kubernetes

➜  kubernetes git:(master) go version
go version go1.15.3 darwin/amd64
```

Beacuse i want test the src ,but howerver i exec make or make all or make generated_files,it always report error

Comment: Please elaborate what you want to achieve. What are you doing, what you are using, whats your configuration. Some details about your environment. Specify your issue.

Comment: I want to make the kubernetes src

Comment: GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/Users/dengyarong/Documents/git/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/Users/dengyarong/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/dengyarong/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/dengyarong/Documents/git/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/dengyarong/Documents/git/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.cn,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"

Comment: GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/tf/6lmyrhzs0mvf9bgxbwkjsy500000gn/T/go-build746926917=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"

Comment: Please add additional information in your question, not comments. It's hard to read all data. But what you want to achieve? You want to integrate Kubernetes with git?

Comment: I want to make generated_files in kubernetes repo,steps follow:1,git clone git@github.com:kubernetes/kubernetes.git $GOPATH/src/kubernetes 2,cd $GOPATH/src/kubernetes/ 3, make generated_files  It always report error. and i don't want to intergrate kubrenetes with git ,just want to make generated_files in kubernetes repo or make all in  kubernetes repo.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: go env -w GOBIN=

k8s will install binary to GOBIN if it is not empty, but k8s try to find prerelease-lifecycle-gen under _output/bin